# Expo Notifications no token production build

Tags: javascript, react-native, notifications, expo, expo-notifications

I created a mock application to test out Expo Notifications and also Firebase Messagging.
Did all the configuration required for the application, downloaded the file provided by firebase `google-services.json` called in the right instances, added all permissions on `app.json`

```
"permissions": [
    "POST_NOTIFICATIONS",
    "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
],
```

requested permission for notifications and registered:

```
export default function App() {
  const [forceReload, setForceReload] = useState(true);
  const [notificationExpoToken, setNotificationExpoToken] = useState('');
  const [notificationDeviceToken, setNotificationDeviceToken] = useState('');

  const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    let tokenExpo;
    let tokenDevice;

    // if android creates the channel before getting permission as documentation says
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
        name: 'default',
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
      });
    }

    // notifications only works on devices, not on emulators (check "if" made as in the documentation)
    if (Device.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
        Alert.alert('ERROR', 'Non è stato possibile ricuperare il token per le notifiche!');
        return;
      }

      tokenExpo = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
      setNotificationExpoToken(tokenExpo);

      tokenDevice = (await Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync()).data;
      setNotificationDeviceToken(tokenDevice);
    } else {
      Alert.alert('ERROR', 'Deve utilizzare un device per le notifiche push!');
    }

    return tokenExpo;
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    (async ()=>{
      await registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    })();
  }, [notificationExpoToken, notificationDeviceToken]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} key={forceReload}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'orange', marginVertical: 10}}>notificationExpoToken:</Text>
      <Text selectable style={{margin: 10}}>{notificationExpoToken}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'blue', marginVertical: 10}}>notificationDeviceToken:</Text>
      <Text selectable style={{margin: 10}}>{notificationDeviceToken}</Text>
      <Button title={"Reload"} onPress={()=>{ setForceReload(!forceReload) }} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

and used my sender to send messages locally, It worked perfectly but once I published the application n it doesn't prompt the token on the screen anymore.

Tried reading a bunch of possible fixes and tried all of them already but nothing seems to work.
Don't know if it's some extra configuration that is needed in production or I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you testing it on simulator or physical device? You need to use a real device.

Comment: Always on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

After all the problem was that inside the `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync` you have to pass the projectId that was supposed to be set automatically.

To fix:

> import Constants from "expo-constants";

Add somewhere the call for the projectId:

> const projectId = Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId;

Pass to the Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync the id as as object:

> const expoToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
> projectId });

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).